# How to write a "*.bat" file?

Tags: c#, batch-file

Why "1.bat" can't run successfully? Any help will be appreciate. "1.bat" was created successfully.It can run without error, but can't rename the files.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory; 
        str += "\\1.bat";
        string txt = "";
        txt = "ren *.mp3 *.wav";  

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(str,false, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write(txt);
        sw.Close();

       Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = str; 
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.Start();         
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _can't run successfully_? Any exception or error message?

Comment: Looks like `\\0.bat`, not `0.bat`. `\\0` is the NULL character and invalid in this context.

Comment: Try setting UseShellExecute on the StartInfo. But you don't need to  call out to a .bat to bulk rename files! You can easily code that up in C#. (You also probably shouldn't assume you have write access to the current directory, and there's a theoretical attack if a malicious user can modify the bat file between you writing it and you executing it: they can make you run arbitrary commands as your user.)

Comment: Nothing happened after I click this file. I can change the filename "*.mp3"(textBox1.Text) into ".wav"(textBox2.Text)

Comment: @rup `UseShellExecute` is the default isn't it

Comment: @hashtabe_0 Instead of presenting code with text boxes whose contents we can only guess at, present code that does not rely on user input.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan D'oh, yes it is - I guess that's not it then. My other points still stand, though.

Comment: When your program is run, `CurrentDirectory` contains a certain value.  It should be the folder where the exe file is located.  Is it also the location where your *mp3 files are stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that your file is being written with a UTF-8 BOM. Try passing `Encoding.Default` to test this out. Or pass `new UTF8Encoding(false)` as the encoding to pass a UTF-8 encoding that omits the BOM.

Another problem (which you just added in an edit) is that you set `UseShellExecute` to `false`. That requires the file you pass to be an executable file. Your file isn't. You need `UseShellExecute` to be `true` to allow the shell to work out how to process your `.bat` file.

And yet another possible problem is that the current directory may not be what you think it is.

When faced with problems like this there is no need at all to be helpless. Do some debugging. Add a `pause` at the end of your batch file and make sure that you can see the console. You'll find out immediately what the problem is. Learning how to debug is just as important as learning how to program. You won't be able to do the latter until you can do the former.

If I were having to do it this way, with an external process, I would:

- Set `UseShellExecute` to `false`.
- Pass `cmd.exe` as the executable file.
- Pass the command to be executed as the command line.

However, it would be much easier to do this directly using C# and so avoid having to spin up external processes.